# Codeigniter flashdata - am I using it correctly?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I learned about flashdata and decided to use it to display messages based on database interactions.

For example if no rows are affected I want to display `Post id is invalid or does not exist!`

In my model

```
function delete_post($post_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->delete('posts'); 

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 0) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('result', 'Post id is invalid or does not exist!');
            redirect('/posts/management');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {

            redirect('/posts/management');
            return TRUE;
        }                   
    }
```

and in my view

```
if ($this->session->flashdata('result') != ''): 
    echo $this->session->flashdata('result'); 
endif;
```

This seems to work fine but there is no example in the CI documentation how to pass flashdata between MVC. I'm concerned.. Am I doing this correctly?

edit: I seem to have left FALSE and TRUE from a prior attempt. I probably won't need that.

Comment: Personally, i use flashdata for system messages, like "Data inserted", "Failure", etc, and pass an array with more, ahm, "persistent" or sensitive values to the view.

Comment: @Jorge, so am I. Database interactions, I meant the same thing. Array is a good idea. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Session data is available anywhere in your application, at any time. Calling it directly from a view file is proper, and so it setting it in a Controller.

There's *no need at all* to pass it as data with `$this->load->view()` - it's redundant. Why assign it to the flashdata in the first place in that case?

The way you're doing it is correct.

**EDIT**: I just saw you are setting it in the Model instead of Controller - which is highly debatable. I would suggest returning a value from your Model call, and setting the message based on it in your Controller instead.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed to know :)

Comment: how is it possible to send a variable from model back to the controller? I know I can in a view but I never tried in controller.

Comment: @CyberJunkie: I mean return true/false, an array of deleted items etc. from the Model, and then check that value in your Controller and set an appropriate message. Example: `$succces = $this->model->delete($id);` where Model returns TRUE/FALSE. `if ( ! $success) // set error message else set success message`

Comment: thank you! It's finally making sense. Not sure why people would debate it tho, setting flashback in the model seems more straightforward to me. (in my case at least)

Answer (score 3):

```
$myArr = array('value 1', 'value 1');

$this->session->set_flashdata('myArray', $myArr);
```

In the view,

```
print_r($this->session->flashdata('myArray'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I just save it in an array and pass it to the view :)

```
 $data['wow_list'] = $this->Wow_model->getWow($uid);

 $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Done. You have added new task.'); 

 $data['flash_message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');


 $this->load->view('wow/index', $data);
```

View

```
<?= $flash_message ?>
```

> Data is passed from the controller to
>   the view by way of an array or an
>   object in the second parameter of the
>   view loading function.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Why bother assigning the data to session in this case at all? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: that can be done directly in view ..I just told my approach .

Comment: What I mean is, why assign it to flashdata, and then assign the flashdata to view data? Why not skip the flashdata part?